# Object Hide on Orientation Change

Tags: android, onconfigurationchanged

I would like to hide only a few elements on orientation change (LANDSCAPE). Where do I put this?

```
Button bt0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
bt0.setVisibility(bt0.GONE);
```

And then, make them comeback on PORTRAIT. They are already defined onCreate.

Comment: As mentioned in the tag, u just need to implement onConfigurationChanged method of Activity right?

Comment: Added the tag just to mark it as relevant to that.

Comment: I think you should forget about the tags, and accept one of the answers...

Comment: I would prefer something like the second one but I am yet to test it out. The point of hiding those elements is to save more screen display space. What's wrong with that tag?

Comment: After days of experimenting. The best solution was to use both suggestions. It works great now. Thanks both of you!

Answer (score 5):

Create two layout folders, one for portrait and one for landscape, `layoput-port` and `layout-land`. Have a look at [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers).

Comment: This should be the way to go

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have two different layouts to display, otherwise defining nearly identical layouts just to hide a few element views will be an overkill, not to mention that you have to maintain two layout xml files. You can just show/hide the view element by checking the orientation at runtime:

```
bt0.setVisibility((getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
```